# MPI compilation with older version returns fatal error

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, mpi, openmpi

I have been working on a project that makes extensive use of mpi and parallelization for scientific computation.

For developing and debugging purposes I have been using my personal computer, where I have installed openMPI 4.1.4, on my machine the project compiles with no errors.

I am now trying to run it on a cluster, the machines are provided and maintained by my institution. But the version of openMPI is much older (1.10.7).

Upon compilation something extremely strange happens, at first the compiler outputs a long list of fatal errors, of which I give an example:

```
../modules/glueballs/plaq_ops.c:15:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
 #include "mpi.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

The strangest thing is that after printing this long list of errors, one for each module containing the call to "mpi.h" **the compiler goes on and compiles the program.** An executable is produced but when I try to launch it it will segfault on startup:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

mpiexec noticed that process rank 5 with PID 10785 on node farm-login-01 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This error message was the outpu of a call with 8 parallel processes.

The project should in principle be compatible with all MPI versions newer than 1.2, some functionalities and modules have been added but, to my knowledge, their usage of mpi is pretty elementary and should not cause problems. I cannot install the newer version mpi on the cluster because of privileges.

What is causing the problem? If the problem lies in the outdated mpi version running on the cluster is there any way I can fix it without having to update mpi?

**EDIT:** The build system uses environment variables $MPI_HOME and $MPI_INCLUDE to locate the mpi resources. In particular mpi.h is inside $MPI_INCLUDE and the build system knows that. The same environment varibale configuration on my pc does not produce any error message

Comment: The message is self explanatory ... Does your build system uses the `mpicc` wrapper or uses the C compiler directly? If Open MPI is provided by the distro, you need the `devel` package in order to build programs.

Comment: That being said, Open MPI can be rebuilt and installed in your $HOME directory, so that might be a better option for you.

Comment: the build system uses mpicc.
If the message is self-explanatory then why does the compilation goes on and actually produces an executable?

Comment: It is surprising that `make` continues with the build and ultimately completes, but I can imagine ways that that might happen.  For the "ultimately completes" part, most of those ways involve the source package you are compiling from containing pre-compiled object files or executables packaged within.

Comment: As a side note, unless you are bundling MPI with your source code, `#include "mpi.h"` should be `#include <mpi.h>`.  But correcting that will not resolve your build issues.

Comment: can you extract the compile command line that causes the error?